# What would be a good commit type when adding more details to log statements (using Conventional Commits)

Tags: git, git-commit, conventional-commits

I added more detail to a log statement eg

from `logger.error('An error occurred')` to `logger.error('An error occurred for ${client.id})`

what would be a good commit type to use under [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd consider that a bug fix (the bug being that there's not enough details in the log to follow up on errors), so I'd say this is simply something like:

```
fix: Add client id to error log message when frobnicating
```